# CSS - removing space between looped form buttons

Tags: php, html, css, button

*edited to include a screenshot

I have a form looped using PHP and am trying to remove the spaces between each submit button. For aesthetic reasons I want to be able to style the space between them exactly. Can someone lend some insight as to how I can accomplish this?

The positionText class seems to help some, and I can't seem to get display:none to have any affect.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
    </head>
<style>
    .positionText {
        line-height: 0%;
        }
</style>
<body>
<div class="positionText">
<?php 

ini_set('display_errors',1);  error_reporting(E_ALL);

$result = file_get_contents('php://input');

require_once 'IRCconfig.php';

$connection = new mysqli($db_hostname, $db_username, $db_password, $db_database);
    if ($connection->connect_error) die($connection->connect_error);

$DATE = empty($result) ? date('Y-m-d') : $result;
    {   
        $query  = "SELECT * FROM CLIENT_CHECKIN WHERE DATE(DATE)='$DATE' ORDER BY F_NAME ASC";
        $result = $connection->query($query);

        if (!$result) die ("Database access failed: " . $connection->error);

        $rows = $result->num_rows;
    }

for ($j = 0 ; $j < $rows ; ++$j)
    {
        $result->data_seek($j);
        $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM);

        echo <<<_END
        <pre>
        <form class="clientSubmit" name="clientSubmit" action="IRCpopulatecheckin.php" method="POST">
        <input type="hidden" name="DATE" value="$row[0]">
        <input type="hidden" name="F_NAME" value="$row[1]">
        <input type="hidden" name="M_NAME" value="$row[2]">
        <input type="hidden" name="L_NAME" value="$row[3]">
        <input type="submit" name="dailyClient" value="$row[1] $row[2] $row[3]">
        </form> 
        </pre>
_END;
    }

?>
</div>
<body>

</html>
```

[image: A sample output]

Comment: Post the rendered HTML output, not the PHP source.

Comment: Why not just add a margin to the submit buttons?

Comment: Not sure exactly what you are trying to do, but try setting all of the inputs on the same line.  That will remove any white space.  You could also use float to accomplish a similar result.

Comment: @jo8691 screen shot added

Comment: @Ricky Goldman setting all the hidden inputs on the same line bring them closer together, but there still is a considerable amount of space. See the photo I added.

Answer (score 0):

You can select the submit button itself using css.

For example:

```
.positionText [type="submit"]{ margin-top: -2px;}
```

You can also select the inputs using

```
[type="hidden"]or.positionText input{}
```

If you want to style each submit separately, try

```
.positionText [type="submit"]:nth-child(2)
```

You can also use

```
:first-child() and :last-child()
```

to select the first and last submit.

Hope that helps.

Comment: This puts on me on the right track, but doesn't get the job done. See the photo I added, the output is more or less the same with adjusted margins and display:none.

Comment: Are you using chrome, because chrome could be adding default browser stylings to your inputs which might be the cause of your issues. Try inspecting with chrome dev tools to see if any stylings are conflicting/over-riding.

Answer (score 0):

Since **form** and **pre** are of block types, you'll need to put a margin: 0 in your CSS.

```
pre,form{margin: 0}
```